# Default framebuffer operations support 16 colors only?

Tags: linux-device-driver, framebuffer

I am writing a custom framebuffer device driver in Linux. One of the structures that has to be filled in is `fb_ops`, which has several methods, `fb_imageblit` being one of them. From what I understand this method is not optional and is supposed to draw the memory contents of an `fb_image` to the `screen_base` member of 'fb_info'. The default one for non-accelerated devices is defined in `cfimgblt.c` . I am working in Linux v5.1 .

I just can't make any sense of this piece of code in `color_imageblit`:

```c
if (p->fix.visual == FB_VISUAL_TRUECOLOR ||
  p->fix.visual == FB_VISUAL_DIRECTCOLOR )
  color = palette[*src];
else
  color = *src;
```

From the documentation I found, I understand that the pseudo palette is for some kind of 16 predefined color modes. They are mapped using `fb_setcolreg`. I get that.
But what I can't find is any way for the driver to use this generic function and be able to draw more than the 16 mapped colors in that palette. Am I missing something ? Have I misinterpreted this method and should I be looking at `fb_write` instead ? Any help would be welcome !

--edit--

The value `visual` in my `fb_info` struct is set to `FB_VISUAL_TRUECOLOR`

--edit--

I do believe that the function that is used when drawing to the image using from a custom user application would indeed use `fb_write`, and that `cfb_imageblit` is only used for a console of some sorts, hence the prefix 'c'. Can someone confirm that ?

Comment: In modern kernels FB drivers should go with DRM framework (see `tinydrm` framework as an example).